# Как заставить устройство с xhdpi-экраном в конкретной ситуации взять картинки из drawable-mdpi?

Tags: eclipse, android, оптимизация, изображения

В папах drawable-mdpi и т.д. лежат картинки для различных экранов. В приложении также есть activity с превьюшками этих картинок. В качестве превьюшек загружаются сами картинки и искусственно сжимаются(`ImageButton` с атрибутом `setAdjustViewBounds(true)`). Для экрана `xhdpi` в принципе хватило бы и картинок `ldpi` в качестве превью, чтобы не жрать мощности на уменьшение `xhdpi`-картинок. Можно ли как-то заставить приложение в конкретном случае вне зависимости от типа экрана загружать картинки именно из `drawable-mdpi`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону `Resources.getDrawableForDensity(int id, int density)`

P.S. Работает только под API >= 15

Answer (score 0):

Положить данную картинку только в папку `drawable-mdpi`. Android сам возьмет ее, но как растянет/сожмет нужно будет поглядеть.

Answer (score 0):

Внести в манифест и настроить по желанию

```
<compatible-screens>
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>

    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>

    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>

    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>
</compatible-screens>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ни как, все твои картинки станут доступными по единому для всех адресу file:///android_res/drawable, ненужные для данного девайса не будут распакованы.